# Is ther any way to check someone edited Wordpress backend code

Tags: php, wordpress, security, cpanel

My website repeatedly showing critical error messages. When I debuging it showing some line of codes are missing from the script. We have multiple admins for website. How to know whether someone editing or not? Is there any chance to happen this other than human effort?

examples

orginal:

```
    mammoth_load_script( 'mammoth-editor' );
    mammoth_load_script( 'tabs' );
}

function mammoth_load_script( $name ) {
    $url = plugins_url( 'mammoth-docx-converter/' . $name . '.js' );
    echo '<script src="'. $url . '?v=1.17.0"></script>';
}
```

In my backend:

```
}

}

function mammoth_load_script( $name ) {
    $url = plugins_url( 'mammoth-docx-converter/' . $name . '.js' );
    echo '<script src="'. $url . '?v=1.17.0"></script>';
}

function mammoth_editor_stylesheets_list( ) {
    return implode( ',', get_editor_stylesheets() );
}
```

it is happening all most all the part of codes. codes where missing from wp-include and wp-admin etc.

any solution to monitor this?

Answer (score 0):

is this project on github? if so, you can use Github desktop. it highlights changes made by Developers altering the codes. and also, it has history feature.